# How to know the White/Black amount in thresholded image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image-processing, threshold

I have a frame, and apply it a grayscale and a thresold function, so I finally get an image in black and white.

How could I know the black or white color amount? Any javascript function to do so? I prefer not to include any extra libraries for that task.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean with 'frame' - an imageData object, uint8 array or ...?

Comment: in your threshold function you should be able to simply count the black and white pixels.